# Ubuntu systemd custom service failing with python script

Tags: python, ubuntu, daemon, systemd

Would like to get some help with systemd daemon service in Ubuntu. I have a python script I wrote to disable the touchscreen on a Dell XPS which is more of a problem than a useful feature. The script works but I don't want to have to launch it all the time which is why the idea came to my head to write a service file and have systemd launch it for me on startup.

The issue I run into is "(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)". This is my first time and I did a little bit of research before I tried this however, I just can't figure it out at this point. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

This is the "systemctl status disable-ts.service output:

```
● disable-ts.service - Disable TouchScreen
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/disable-ts.service; enabled; vendor 
  preset: enabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-02-23 01:31:27 PST; 
  6min ago
  Process: 2667 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python disable-ts.py 
 (code=exited,status=1/FAILURE)

 Feb 23 01:31:27 roman-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: disable-ts.service: Service 
 hold-off time over, schedul
 Feb 23 01:31:27 roman-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: disable-ts.service: 
 Scheduled restart job, restart coun
 Feb 23 01:31:27 roman-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: Stopped Disable TouchScreen.
 Feb 23 01:31:27 roman-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: disable-ts.service: Start 
 request repeated too quickly.
 Feb 23 01:31:27 roman-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: disable-ts.service: Failed 
 with result 'exit-code'.
 Feb 23 01:31:27 roman-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: Failed to start Disable 
 TouchScreen.
```

This is the service file itself:

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable TouchScreen
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=roman
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/home/roman/Python-Scripts/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python disable-ts.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After I created this I did run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable disable-ts.service
sudo systemctl start disable-ts.service
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the exact same problem today. I searched everywhere for a solution but nothing worked! I came across this question above and just like user Sean DiSanti above, I placed 'simple' in type and specified a workingdirectory. It worked!

Here is the full service file that fixed my problem.

```
[Unit]
Description=Upload Data
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/aws/webUpload/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 upload_data.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this exact problem myself today, almost entirely the same setup except I was using 'simple' for type, and had not specified user or workingdirectory. Adding the working directory worked for me.