# systemd service activation for Python script fails

Tags: python-3.7, raspbian, daemon, systemd

I want to register a python script as a daemon service, executed at system startup and running continuously in the background. The script opens network sockets, a local log file and executes a number of threads. The script is well-formed and runs without any compilation or runtime issues.

I used below service file for registration:

```
[Unit]
Description=ModBus2KNX Gateway Daemon
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/ModBusDaemon.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Starting the service results in below error:

```
● ModBusDaemon.service - ModBus2KNX Gateway Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ModBusDaemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-01-04 21:46:29 CET; 6min ago
  Process: 1390 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/ModBusDaemon.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1390 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 04 21:46:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started ModBus2KNX Gateway Daemon.
Jan 04 21:46:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ModBusDaemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 04 21:46:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ModBusDaemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Appreciate your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related posts brought me to the resolution for my issue. [Ubuntu systemd custom service failing with python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840385/ubuntu-systemd-custom-service-failing-with-python-script/65570035#65570035) refers to the same issue. The proposed solution adding the *WorkingDirectory* to the *Service* section resolved the issue for me. Though, I could not find the adequate systemd documentation outlining on the implicit dependency.

Answer (score 1):

As MBizm saim you must also add WorkingDirectory.

And After that you must also run these commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable your_service.service
sudo systemctl start your_service.service
```